# OpenAI's Whisper Error ("TypeError: transcribe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'audio'")

Tags: python, openai-whisper

I am trying out OpenAI's whisper library in Python, but I am getting an error when I try to run it.

This was the first the error I was getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/---/PycharmProjects/Projects/whisper-test.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = whisper.transcribe(audio_data)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: transcribe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'audio'
```

**Update**: After specifying the parameters in the `whisper.transcribe()` function, the error message changed slightly:

```
/Users/---/PycharmProjects/Projects/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py:115: UserWarning: FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead
  warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/---/PycharmProjects/Projects/whisper-test.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = whisper.transcribe(model=model, audio=audio_data, verbose=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/---/PycharmProjects/Projects/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 122, in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, model.dims.n_mels, padding=N_SAMPLES)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/---/PycharmProjects/Projects/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 141, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = torch.from_numpy(audio)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got bytes)
```

This is my updated code:

```py
import whisper

with open("hello.mp3", "rb") as audio_file:
    audio_data = audio_file.read()

model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = whisper.transcribe(model=model, audio=audio_data, verbose=True)

print(result["text"])
```

I have also tried with a .m4a file, and pasting the file url directly into the `whisper.transcribe('audio')` method, but they all return the same error.

Also, additional question:
*Does the Whisper library require an OpenAI API Key?*

Comment: Does this help? `result = whisper.transcribe(audio_data, verbose = True)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the .mp3 file directly without reading.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: result = model.transcribe("hello.mp3")
like this, if it doesn't work. Can you show me the code and error again.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the `fp16=False` parameter to the `transcribe()` function.

Demo code:

```py
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model('base')
result = model.transcribe('audio.wav', fp16=False)

print(result['text'])
```

Thank you to [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/HbY51mVKrcE?t=149) for showing me this!